# Find the value $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z^{100}+1}dz$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

> Find the value
>    $$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z^{100}+1}dz.$$

Im getting struck and my thinking is that by Cauchy theorem it must be zero as $|z| = 2$ is analytic inside ... is  my thinking is correct or not pliz verified.

Comment: Where are the roots of $z^{100}$ +1=0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. No, the integrand is not analytic inside $|z|=2$. Actually there are $100$ (simple) poles in $|z|<2$!! Use the [residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem):
$$\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z^{100}+1}dz=2\pi i\sum_{k=1}^{100}\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{1}{z^{100}+1},z=w_k\right)$$
where $w_1,w_2,\dots,w_{100}$ are the roots of the equation $z^{100}=-1$.
You may also use the [residue at infinity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity)'s definition.

Comment: +1 thanks,,@Robert Z,,,pliz elaborate  with explaination, ..i was reading the residue thorem,,,,not getting so much

Comment: For the evaluations of the residues see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122786/formula-for-calculating-residue-at-a-simple-pole

Comment: Residue at infinity is much easier, I wonder if it is not the point with the exercise.

Comment: @ Robert Z  ,,,i was trying  that i take (z -(-1)^1/100),,here i can not   define residue...

Comment: Do you know how to evaluate the complex roots of complex number? See for example https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870884/find-the-8th-complex-roots-of-81i

Comment: @ Robert Z  u just tell me the answer that what is value ? ..after that  i will  try  ,,,

Comment: What is the value of what?

Comment: @ Robert Z the  value $\int_{|z|=2}\frac{1}{z^{100}+1}dz$?

Comment: @ RobertZ  im very sorry...ur explaination is  not easy to understand as compared to DonAntonio

Comment: @lomber lego Do you really understand DonAntonio's answer? BTW I gave you a hint (not a full answer!!) where I also suggested the use of the residue at infinity.

Comment: @RobertZ,,,u have said that  |Z|= 2 is not analytics     that  confused me and other is that   i can not  able to find residue at infinity   from ur given hints,,,,,but anyways  im really thankful  to u  for ur effort and giving  me for such valuable time,,,,

Comment: Yes, the function $\frac{1}{z^{100}+1}$ is NOT analytic inside $|z|=2$ because it has 100 singularities inside that disc. Moreover I gave you the link  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_at_infinity which is exactly the definition used by DonAntonio.

Comment: yes,,,@RobertZ,,,,but after seeing DonAntonio answer  i understand ur given answer

Comment: This is a mystery to me...

Answer (score 3):

All the function's poles are simple and are the roots of

$$\;z^{100}=-1=e^{\pi i+2k\pi i}=e^{\pi i(1+2k)}\;,\;\;k=0,1,2,...,99$$

Thus, **all** the residues are within the domain enclosed by the given curve, and thus you can calculate the integral using the residue at infinity theorem (instead of evaluating $\,100\,$ residues...!), so:

$$\frac1{z^2}f\left(\frac1z\right)=\frac1{z^2\left(\frac1{z^{100}}+1\right)}=\frac1{z^2}\left(1-z^{-100}+z^{-200}-z^{-300}+\ldots\right)$$

and we can see the residue is zero, and from here

$$\oint_{|z|=2}\frac{dz}{z^{100}+1}=0$$

Comment: @   DonAntonio.......thanks  a lots   that mean  0  is the answer